# Как посмотреть код импортируемого класса в Android Studio и Intelij IDEA?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек

Как посмотреть код класса, который я использую благодаря импорту библиотеки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зажмите `Ctrl` и щелкните левой кнопкой мыши по классу или любому его методу

Для Mac, если не ошибаюсь, `Command`